# where is the disk capacity stored?

Tags: hard-drive, dd, capacity

In short, if I do `dd` disk-to-disk (e.g. `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb`), is the capacity of the whole disk also copied?

For example, if `sda` is actually 1TB and `sdb` 2TB, after the `dd`, which would a Linux system regard `sdb` as, 1TB or 2TB?

I assume that the disk capacity is recorded in a separate ROM or small non-volatile storage, not in any sector of the disk. Or, maybe a couple of sectors of a physical disk might be always reserved.

I'd like to migrate systems on an old 1TB hard disk to a new 2TB one with minimal pain. The old disk won't be used. I thought `dd` might do. The only part that I wasn't sure is if I do `dd` & the size of the disk capacity is ever copied just like the partition table, the new 2TB disk would become 1TB. I wanted to make sure before actually doing `dd`.

My Google search was not fruitful, so finally I decided to post a question here.

If all the systems were Linux, I'd consider `rsync` partition-to-partition & `grub-install`. However, unfortunately, I have one Windows and do not have a Windows installation usb. I am not sure how to re-install and/or reconfigure Windows boot loader after `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDD size in actual "physical" terms of platter/heads is stored in a internal ROM but it is not user-accessible. Modern HDDs (and SSDs) expose an abstraction called LBA (logical block addressing), which basically tell the OS how many user-addressable sectors the disk has.

`dd` simply reads until EOF (end-of-file), which can either be the end of disk or partition. Copying your entire 1 TB disk to the 2 TB one with `dd` will end with a maximum of 1 TB partitioned space on you destination disk - ie: the original MBR/GPT does not know anything about the additional space at the end.

Think about a small box put inside a larger one: object inside the smaller box does not "know" anything about the available outer space. At the same time, to use the additional space provided by your 2 TB disk you need to modify the original MBR/GPT creating additional partitions or expanding the last one.

When copying at user level via tools as `cp` or `rsync`, you do not need this simply because your 2 TB disk will (hopefully) be already partitioned to use all the available space, with the filesystem sized according.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I caused some miscommunication. I was wondering if I do dd, I worried that I would not be able to "expand the last partition" or create a new one in the unallocated space." I thought there must be some meta-information that tells, say, parted or gparted the maximum usable capacity of the give disk. If that maximum capacity information were in the partition table, I thought the 1TB would be never used. However, it seems like the size is in a ROM, and there's a protocol for an OS to access it.